# VS Code not showing Icon preview (Dart/Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

As you can see by the attached image, the icon preview does not load.
Restarting did not help.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

[image: VS Image not working]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try running `flutter clean` and upgrading the Flutter SDK and see if it solves the issue? Icon previews works without issues on VS Code on my end, I'm currently on Flutter 2.5

[image: Icon preview]